# Full calendar Jquery plugin, I want to show month instead of prev and next arrow

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

For example, I want to display a month instead of prev and next arrow. ?I have added the image below.

[image]

This is my code,

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
          header: {
            left: 'prev',
            center: '',
            right: 'next'
          },
          contentHeight: 1050,
          columnHeaderFormat: 'dddd',
          navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
          editable: true,
          eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
          events: [
            {
              title: 'All Day Event',
              start: '2018-09-01'
            }
          ]
        });
    });
```

Please help me to fix this,

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show your code please?

Comment: Already i have added the code, please check.

Comment: Have you tried the following: header: {
            left: 'prev',
            center: 'month',
            right: 'next'
          },

Comment: Yes, Its showing arrows for next and prev, I want to display month instead of arrows.

Comment: I don't know how it can be done using fullcalendars lib but I guess you could write a function to change the text of fc-prev-button and fc-next-button.

Comment: ok karen, Thanks

Comment: yeah there is no built-in functionality for this in fullCalendar, you'd have to write something custom

Comment: I have done Adyson, I created custom function for that.